# Displaying .tif band values using R

Tags: r, raster, tiff

I'm very new to programming in R and i'm having some problems.

I have a .tif raster with a lot of bands, and I needed a vector to read and display the values from each band, but i don't seen to know how to do it.

I tried using the raster library, but probably did something wrong

Comment: Welcome to SO, Joao Pedro Tanaka! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.